# Can't pass object property name through function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, properties, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an object property name through a function parameter, but it doesn't works. Here is my script (details below, after it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myButton()">Try it</button>

<p id="display"></p>
<p id="display2"></p>

<script>

var person = {"name":"dupont","surname":"bob"};

function myButton() {    
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = person.name;    
    function personInfoDetails(x) {
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = person[x];
    }
    personInfoDetails(name);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to display "dupont", the stored value under the property "name" of my object "person" through the function "personInfoDetails(x)". To do it I execute this function replacing its paramater "x" through the property "name" of my object "person". But it displays "undefined".

Here is a [live preview of this script](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOO9EMU5FRWI).

I all ready read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369463/how-to-pass-objects-property-name-to-drawimage) and try to apply its solution for my problem but it still doesn't work.

Thank you very much in advance for your solutions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `name` with quotes `""`

```js
var person = {
  "name": "dupont",
  "surname": "bob"
};

function myButton() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = person.name;

  function personInfoDetails(x) {
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = person[x];
  }
  personInfoDetails("name");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<button onclick="myButton()">Try it</button>
<p id="display"></p>
<p id="display2"></p>
```

Comment: Ho wow ! I am working around this problem since hours (I am a js programing beginer). And this was the solution... adding quotes... Thank you so much ! And thank  you for your fast answer. Very cool

Comment: Is it also possible to call the function personInfoDetails() with its parameter "name" without quotes? Doing like so (I know my code doesn't work but it is to explain my idea): `function personInfoDetails(x) {
    var y = " + x + ";
    document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = person[y];
 }
    personInfoDetails(name);`

Comment: @mosis no, because the compiler is unable to found the variable `name`.  Further, this isn't correct `var y = " + x + "`.

Comment: All right, thank you very much. I had the hope that something like this could be possible, through some string manipulation, converting the inputed parameter **name** ( personInfoDetails(**name**); ) into a **"name"** wich I can use to display the corresponding content of my object **person**